# PHP cannot pass two parameter to another php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, proxy

I need to call php and get data from another server and I am using proxy.php to call from ajax.

**proxy.php**

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
?>
```

And my code looks

```
    function scanFunction(){

        var url="http://address/scan.php?user=user1&video=video1";
         console.log(url);

        url = 'proxy.php?url='+url;

        $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {

        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr) {
           if(jsonStr.length>0){
            var obj = jsonStr;
             console.log(obj);
            }
           else{
              console.log(" error...");
           }

       }

    });

}
```

And this code works fine when I use one parameter to the url passing to proxy.php where as second argument missing

That is

`echo $url;` inside proxy.php print 
`http://address/scan.php?user=user1`

event I pass two argument like, 
   `proxy.php?url="http://address/scan.php?user=user1&video=video1"`

That is second argument video missing inside proxy.php and so I am not getting expected result.

Comment: What do you think the `data:` property of an `.ajax` call might be used for

Comment: Quick explanation: once you have the first `&` in adress-scan url, it will be seen as a second paramater on the `get`. You'll have to find a way to encode it and then set it as `'proxy.php?url='+encoded_url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having issues with your `GET` variables in the `GET['url']` variable.

Try encoding your url when you send it to `proxy.php` to avoid such issues.

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("http://address/scan.php?user=user1&video=video1");
url = 'proxy.php?url='+url;
```

Then on the PHP side you need to decode it.

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
if (is_string($url)) {
    $url = urldecode($url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `data:` property of the ajax call to pass as much or as many parameters as you like

```
function scanFunction(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'proxy.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
                url: 'http://address/scan.php',
                user: 'user1',
                video: 'video1'
              },
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function (jsonStr) {
           if(jsonStr.length>0){
               var obj = jsonStr;
               console.log(obj);
           } else {
               console.log(" error...");
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Then build whatever you want from those parameters in the php script

> Oh and you used `type: 'POST'` in your javascript, so you should be using the `$_POST` array in your PHP script.

proxy.php

```
<?php

$url = $_POST['url'] . '?user=' . $_POST['user'] . '&video=' . $_POST['video'];

$json=file_get_contents($url);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Actually I need generalized proxy.php to use, I have to call it from many place with different parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`proxy.php` cannot know which arguments are meant for it, and which are meant for `scan.php`.  Eg, When you call url:

```
proxy.php?url=http://address/scan.php?user=user1&video=video1
```

Your proxy scripts thinks that the query parameters are:

```
url:"http://address/scan.php?user=user1"
video:"video1"
```

But your intent was for everything after `url` to be one parameter.  A better approach is to use `POST` parameters instead of URL query parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        resource_url: "http://address/scan.php?user=user1&video=video1"
    },
    ....
});
```

Now, in **proxy.php**:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $url=$_POST['resource_url'];
    $json=file_get_contents($url);
    echo $json;
?>
```